# Reuse a password in Windows

Tags: passwords

I know this go against every computer security expert but is there a way to reuse an old password after you change it?   It seems like if a user name is tied to a Microsoft account (live or outlook) this is not possible.   Is there any way around this?   Thanks!

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From software side there is no way because an Admin account can start *CMD* before Windows login. But physically it's possible to access data when the disk is not encrypted the HardDisk. There is option called LinuxBoot(Live USB) disk to add and Admin in Windows but not works in Windows 8/8.1.